# Calling an OSB-WebService from a BPEL Process with a Conversation ID

Tags: oracle11g, bpel, osb, soa-suite

I'm having trouble with invoking an OSB-WebService from a SOA Suite 11g BPEL Process.

- If I do **not** specify a Conversation ID, it works.
- If I do specify a Conversation ID (I'm using the ECID), I get the error: "Unable to access the following endpoint(s):"

The Error gets thrown, as soon as the response message from the OSB WebService arrives.

Note: the response message from the OSB WebService should **not** reinvoke the BPEL process, but only confirm that the OSB received the Message. (The Conversation ID will be used later.)

My hypothesis is that there is a mix-up between the Conversation ID and the Dialog-ID.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use ConversationID, is it an asynchronous webservice call?

Comment: Yes, it is an asynchronous webservice.